# Serverless TypeError: chalk(...).dim is not a function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to test the serverless lambda function using the command

Command

```
serverless invoke local -f send --log --stage test
```

Error

```
TypeError: chalk(...).dim is not a function
```

Entire stacktrace:

```
Type Error ---------------------------------------------

  TypeError: chalk(...).dim is not a function
      at /snapshot/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:83:47
      at /snapshot/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
      at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.init (/snapshot/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:72:8)
      at /snapshot/serverless/bin/serverless.js:74:8
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/serverless/bin/serverless.js:64:4)
      at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1261:22)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:813:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:14)
      at Function.Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1316:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              12.13.1
     Framework Version:         1.64.0 (standalone)
     Plugin Version:            3.4.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

This command is run inside the directory which has serverless.yml, requirements.txt, handler.py.

Unable to understand why this error occurs and what's the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the Standalone version of the Serverless Framework.

I've opened a PR to address this https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/7412

In the meantime, this bug is caused by the fact that Serverless Framework v1.65.0 was just released. You can resolve this by upgrading, which will cause this erroneous codepath to not be called.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the quick response and help! appreciate it! serverless upgrade --stage test worked. weird why I have to keep mentioning the stage when I am in the virtualenv.. but nonetheless it unblocked me.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :D